# Book page fields inherit content from parent

Tags: nodes, entities

I created a book with several book pages of a specific content type. I am trying to inherit the values of some fields from the top page of the book to the child pages so that i don't have to fill them manually on each page.

I tried the "Field default token" module with no luck. Actually it doesn't display the value of the token that i select.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was fairly simple after all.
I created two content types and used a field with Entity Reference to pass the values from the first content type to the second one.